# dplyr unique rows sample_n

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to get random samples based on group for a relatively large data frame.  I need to get unique results for each group member only - I can't have results duplicate for an individual member or overall.

I have used this code successfully for small samples:

```
    processors2 <- processors%>%filter(str_detect(Person.Who.Changed.Object, "A0")) %>% 
      group_by(User)%>% sample_n(., 2)
```

However, if I use the below similar code, I get multiple duplicates both within  groups and overall (i.e. member 1 and member 3 get the same row of data, and member 1 gets 2 of a different row all to itself).

```
claimallocator2 <- claimallocator%>%
  group_by(User)%>% sample_n(80, weight = Claim.Amt)
```

Additionally, it makes no difference if I add replace = FALSE.  I am still getting duplicates.

The expected output (obviously on a drastically smaller scale):

```
User    Warranty.Claim  Claim.amt
User 1  1   500
User 1  2   1000
User 1  3   1500
User 1  4   2000
User 1  5   2500
User 2  6   3000
User 2  7   3500
User 2  8   4000
User 2  9   4500
User 2  10  5000
User 2  11  5500
User 2  12  6000
User 3  13  6500
User 3  14  7000
User 3  15  7500
User 3  16  8000
User 3  17  8500
User 3  18  9000
User 3  19  9500
User 3  20  10000
User 3  21  10500
User 3  22  11000
```

What I am actually getting:

```
    User    Warranty.Claim  Claim.amt
    User 1  1   500
    User 1  1   500
    User 1  3   1500
    User 1  4   2000
    User 1  5   2500
    User 2  6   3000
    User 2  7   3500
    User 2  8   4000
    User 2  9   4500
    User 2  10  5000
    User 2  11  5500
    User 2  12  6000
    User 3  13  6500
    User 3  14  7000
    User 3  15  7500
    User 3  16  8000
    User 3  17  8500
    User 3  18  9000
    User 3  19  9500
    User 3  8   4000
    User 3  21  10500
    User 3  22  11000
```

Comment: Please add a sample of the input data too. This **Person.Who.Changed.Object,** is no where in the data sets shown above.

Comment: That was an example I added only to show that I have a working example for a small sample.  My assumption is that everyone is relatively familiar with dplyr and wouldn't want/need to run that one.

Comment: Not really, if it has no use in the post, then adding it is as good as pointless, best to not include it at all. I personally always look at the data first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach: first remove the duplicated rows, then group by user and sample the desired number of cases.

```r
# create toy data
df <- data.frame(user=sample(1:10,1000,T),
                 warranty=sample(1:10,1000,T),
                 claim=sample(1:10,1000,T))

# count number of duplicate user-warranty-claim trios
df %>% count(user,warranty,claim) %>% arrange(desc(n))

# remove duplicates, sample 2 cases per user
df %>% group_by(user,warranty,claim) %>% slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% group_by(user) %>% sample_n(2)
```

Comment: Almost there!  Your method gets rid of duplicates within each group, but I still am getting some overall (like group 1 and group 7 have a shared record for example).

Comment: I don't understand -- if the groups are different, then wouldn't they be unique records? If you want to sample unique records of `Warranty.Claim` and `Claim.amt`, then remove `User` from the `group_by` call and `then slice(1)`.

Answer (score -1):

You may check the `replace` option in the `sample_n()` function

Comment: I should mention that I have tried replace = FALSE and it makes no difference.  i will update my question.